# JS instance name as a parameter

Tags: javascript, class, instantiation

Is there a way to call a function which will call a class constructor, giving it the arguments, especially the instance name, provided in the call ?

The most important thing is that I want to pass the name of the instance I want to be created.

In other words, is there a way to have this working :

```
function instantiationOfSomething(instanceName, param1, param2, param3) {               
    instanceName = new mySomethingClass({
        ...
    });         
}

//call #1
instantiationOfSomething("circle", 2, 8, 87);

//call #2
instantiationOfSomething("ellipse", 2, 85, 87);
```

I don't have any possibility to act on the constructor, e.g. `instantiationOfSomething(...)` is not a part of my code but is a part of an API.

Here is a real code example (Google Maps API v3):

```
makeMarker("markerName1", latlng1, "label1", "Title1");
makeMarker("markerName2", latlng2, "label2", "Title2");

function makeMarker (name, latlng, label, title) { 

    //here is the tricky part
    instanceName = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        label: label,
        draggable: true,
        title: title
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the scope you would like to set a new instance? Anyway, you'd need `eval` to create a variable name dynamically, I'd prefer using objects here.

Comment: Maybe consider the `call` and `apply` functions since they both allow you to specify the object as the first argument?

Comment: the scope I'd like to have is global, because I need to add listeners to the objects I created (I work with Google Maps API v3). I already tried eval but I'm missing something I think...

Comment: I think you could do this better by not to pass any name, rather make a call like `window.ellipse = instantiationOfSomething(2, 85, 87);` and in the called function`return new mySomethingClass({...});`

Comment: I don't have the possibility to act on the constructor, because I use Google Maps API v3.

Comment: In that case it's maybe better to post some real code you have. Notice, that I've updated my previous comment, "constructor" was an incorrect term, it is now replaced with "called function", that is something you can control, isn't it?

Comment: see my example above. I can't control the constructor (new google.maps.Marker...) but I can control the function that calls it (makeMarker). Of course, according to the example, I could write 2 separate calls to the constructor within two separate functions, but assume that I must create 20 markers, I wondered how I could do it...

Comment: return new mySomethingClass({...}); works fine, that was the first solution I used. But if I do so, I can't set listeners to the newly created object within the function, I have to do it separately. Hence, I asked this question...but maybe there is no way to achieve it without dirty code

Comment: how can I hard-code it to the property ?

Comment: As you did before (when returned an instance). Anyway, I'm not familiar with Google Maps, but doesn't it have its own event handling model? Afaik `new google.maps.Marker()` is asynchronous, hence you can't attach an event handler in `makeMarker` to the newly-created object in any case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it too ;) Before I asked the question, I was dealing with two separate functions. In each one, there was something like myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(). Within each function, it was possible to add a listener to myMarker...and it worked ! That is the reason why I don't want to return the constructor : I need to add event-listeners and other stuff to the newly created object, and performing a return prevents me from doing it

Answer (score 1):

### Simple answer

```
function createVariable(name, value)
{
    window[name] = value;
}

// Usage:
createVariable("x", 5);
console.log(x === 5); // true
```

### Explanation

There is a term [**context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in JavaScript. When you access a variable `variableName` you are actually accessing a `variableName` property in the current context.

Default context in browsers is `window` object. So, actually, these statements in a **default** (outer) context are identical:

```js
var variableName = "Hello World";

document.body.innerHTML += variableName + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += this.variableName + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += window.variableName + "<br/>";
```

In JavaScript, talking about object [**property accessing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), you may use both dot notation or brackets notation:

```js
var variableName = {
  propertyName: "Hello World"
};

document.body.innerHTML += variableName.propertyName + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += variableName['propertyName'] + "<br/>";
```

However, the last one allows use of characters that can't be used with dot notation, like spaces. Also, it allows dynamic names.

Combining all above, you can easily instantiate a variable with a dynamic name by assigning a property of default `window` context:

```js
function createVariable(name, value)
{
    window[name] = value;
}

createVariable('stackoverflow', 'Hello World');
document.body.innerHTML = stackoverflow;
```

For example, in case of marker, it can be done this way:

```
function makeMarker (name, latlng, label, title) {
    // not that tricky part anymore
    window[name] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        label: label,
        draggable: true,
        title: title
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't pass the name to the constructor. However, I was able to use only one function to call the constructor. For those who are interested, the solution is quite simple, even if it is not "beautiful". I just racked my brains too much, instead of taking the shortest path. Here is how I did :

```
markerName1 = makeMarker(latlng1, "label1", "Title1");
markerName2 = makeMarker(latlng2, "label2", "Title2");

function makeMarker (latlng, label, title) {

//the scope is local
var temp= new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            label: label,
            draggable: true,
            title: title
        });
temp.dosomething();
temp.addListener('dblclick', function(event) {
    alert('Damn, you double-clicked me !');
})

//temp is returned 
return temp;
}
```